# Plone Portal Workflow Control Panel

Tags: workflow, plone

Which attributes can i put instead the (Defaul) on the poral_workflow (control panel) ?

[image]

Comment: You can leave it **empty** (no workfklow assigned to the type) or a name of another workflow (all defined workflow are found in the "*Contents*" tabs.

Comment: Consider the plone documentation about workflows -> https://developer.plone.org/content/workflow.html

Comment: a site-admin would normally use http://yourhost/Plone/@@types-controlpanel to set the workflow for content types.
this form also allows to map states of the former workflow to states of the new when changing workflows.